# What would be the opposite of Room 101?

Tags: word-choice, phrases, expressions, terminology, antonyms

Room 101 is known as the place where all horrible things are placed far away from visibility. What would be the opposite, a place where you display the things you love and enjoy?

Comment: Santa's Grotto.

Comment: This is an interesting use of 101.  Here, 101 is used in place of introductory or tutorial, as in "Here's a 101 on baking."  Our "Room 101" is the closet.  I'm not sure there is a counter to it.  But things are displayed on a mantel, and placed in a hope chest (particular to marriage).  I think this is a great question. +1

Comment: I gather "Room 101" Is a reference to something in the book "1984" that even those who actually read it no longer remember.  Such memories as there are are only kept alive by an old BBC comedy series (and there the reference is as much to a conference room in an old BBC building).  As such it's hard to believe that an "antonym" can be conceived of that will produce any sort of instant recognition.

Comment: Though "The room full of precious puppy videos" does come to mind.

Comment: "101 Moor"? Sounds opposite, no?

Comment: @A Rana   perhaps you could edit your question to provide an example sentence showing how you would like to use this word.  As it stands, there is no definitive opposite.  ‘*The mantle*” is a place where we display things we’re proud of. But although it is an architectural detail in a house, it’s not a room.

Comment: In Australia, such things "go straight to the pool room".

Comment: This is an easy one. The opposite of Room 101 is Room 010. That's the place where all good things are displayed openly.

Comment: BBC TV chat show (series): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Room_101_%28TV_series%29

Answer (score 1):

The connotations of "Room 101" cannot be divorced from its source, Orwell's *1984*.  Room 101 is a torture chamber in the Ministry of Love, in which enemies of the state are subjected to their particular phobias, their worst nightmares.  It's not a place where "all horrible things are placed"; rather it's a place where individual and individualized horrible things are done.  The room's name carries with it a banality that underscores its terrible nature, working in much the same way as the -- may I use the adjective? -- Orwellian name of the ministry.  Given the particularity of the use in a work of (nominal) fiction, I doubt you could find an antonym unless there were a reverse *1984*.

Comment: In the film of *1984*, the building in which torture chamber 101 is located is [Senate House](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Senate_House_(University_of_London)), in Malet Street, the administrative HQ of London University. It is a monolithic 1930s' Art Deco construction of the most forbidding appearance, with terrifyingly bereft corridors in which you can hear footsteps approaching from seemingly miles away.  I believe many who work there will ironically refer to it, on occasion, as the Ministry of Love.